# Writing a program to find out the sum of the negative elements and positive elements of the array

Tags: javascript

My code runs well up until the point it is expected to return the result - it does not add up any of the values entered by the user.

```
a = (prompt("a:"));
b = (prompt("b:"));
c = (prompt("c:"));

negativeSum = Number(0);
positiveSum = Number(0);

var test = [a, b, c];

for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {

    if (isNaN(test[i])) {
        alert(test[i] + " : incorrect input.");
    }

    else

    if (test[i] < 0) {
        alert(test[i] + " : positive.")
        negativeSum = Number(test[i]++);
    }
    else {
        alert(test[i] + " : positive.")
        positiveSum = Number(test[i]++);
    }
}

alert(positiveSum + " : sum of +ve elements");
alert(negativeSum + " : sum of -ve elements");
```

Comment: Yeah its optional practical work for those wanting to learn more about JS. I'm just going through a few exercises on it because I've only started learning JS a month a ago!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn't sum of negatives always less then sum of positives. 
if you speaking about absolute diff. 
than try

```
if (test[i] < 0) {
        alert(test[i] + " : positive.")
        negativeSum += Number(test[i]);
    }
    else {
        alert(test[i] + " : positive.")
        positiveSum += Number(test[i]);
    }

//after the loop 

return Math.abs(negativeSum) > positiveSum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things - no need for `Number(0)` - just using `0` will do.

The line:

```
 positiveSum = Number(test[i]++);
```

Simply assigns the value of `test[i]` + 1 (this is what the post increment `++` operator does) to `positiveSum`. It doesn't add it up to `positiveSum` (same is true for `negativeSum`.

This should work better:

```
negativeSum = 0;
positiveSum = 0;

var test = [a, b, c];

for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {

    if (isNaN(test[i])) {
        alert(test[i] + " : incorrect input.");
    }

    else

    if (test[i] < 0) {
        alert(test[i] + " : positive.")
        negativeSum += test[i];
    }
    else {
        alert(test[i] + " : positive.")
        positiveSum += test[i];
    }
}
```

In my code the line:

```
negativeSum += test[i];
```

Is equivalent to:

```
negativeSum = negativeSum + test[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not summing anything, you're incrementing each number you've input. You want positiveSum += (each number).

You should also convert the element to a number before doing the comparison to zero and the rest.

Comment: He isn't just incrementing - he is assigning the result to the variable that is supposed to be the sum instead of adding it to the sum.

Comment: @Oded I know; I prefer not just handing out answers when it's clear someone is just learning.